# Gradle can't run docker task on Mac

Tags: java, docker, gradle, docker-for-mac

I'm using `gradle-docker` plugin from Palantir. When I try to build docker I receive following error message:

`Starting process 'command 'docker''. Working directory: /Users/msolomkin/Projects/glossary/discovery-server/build/docker Command: docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=discovery-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -t solomkinmv/discovery-server .`

But when I go to the working directory (`/Users/msolomkin/Projects/glossary/discovery-server/build/docker`) manually and run command `docker build --build-arg JAR_FILE=discovery-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -t solomkinmv/discovery-server .` everything works fine.

Also, my Travis is able to build docker image. Looks like it is problem of my Docker installation for Mac.

Docker for Mac version: 17.12.0-ce-mac49 (21995)

Gradle version: 4.4.1

Here is my task configuration:

```
docker {
    name "solomkinmv/${bootJar.baseName}"
    println "==> Docker task for ${name}"
    files bootJar.archivePath
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "${bootJar.archiveName}"])
}
```

And here is the link to GitHub: https://github.com/solomkinmv/glossary/tree/discovery-server/discovery-server

What is the proper way of configuring env variables for Docker for Mac to be able to run gradle tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Try *removing* all of your `${DOCKER_*}` environment variables and running it. Many `docker` utilities manipulate these variables and sometimes they get inconsistent values. I found out that just removing them solved my problems for running the `docker` command from the propmt.

Hope this helps.